# Using data binding to launch animations in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, animation, mvvm

I am trying to adapt a simple WPF application to use the Model-View-ViewModel pattern. On my page I have a couple of animations:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="storyboardRight"
                x:Key="storyboardRight">
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="da3"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="labelRight"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0"
                         To="1"
                         Duration="0:0:0.5" />
        <DoubleAnimation x:Name="da4"
                         Storyboard.TargetName="labelRight"
                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="1"
                         To="0"
                         BeginTime="0:0:1"
                         Duration="0:0:0.5" />
    </Storyboard>
    ...
</Page.Resources>
```

Currently I begin the animation in the code behind, and can listen to the Completed event to do something when it finishes with the following code:

```
storyboardRight = (Storyboard)TryFindResource("storyboardRight");
storyboardRight.Completed += new EventHandler(storyboardRight_Completed);
storyboardRight.Begin(this);
```

Is there a way of data binding the storyboard to my ViewModel so that it starts on an event raised by the ViewModel and can call-back into that ViewModel when it is finished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the opportunity to put this question to Microsoft's Josh Twist, who kindly took the time to provide an answer to this problem. The solution is to use a `DataTrigger` in combination with an enum in the ViewModel to launch the Storyboard, and this in turn requires putting the page into a `ContentPresenter`. To handle animation completion, a small amount of code behind was required to make a call into an `ICommand` on the ViewModel.

Read Josh's post [here](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Model_View_ViewModel_and_Animation.aspx) for a full description of the solution.

Comment: This solution only requires putting the page into a CpntentPresenter if you use a DataTemplate. It is possible to use it in a control's own style's triggers rather than the DataTemplate's triggers if you are animating properties of the control.

Comment: The link to Josh Twists site is broken. Apparently Josh's entire site is broke (no blog articles load) and when I try emailing him it just bounces. Anyone know how to contact Josh and remedy the situation?

Comment: @SimonGillbee I've sent him a message on twitter

Answer (score 2):

I did this by a using DataTrigger and binding it to a property in my ViewModel.  When the "FlashingBackGround" property gets set to "ON" the Storyboard animation starts.

Also make sure to include in your project a reference to "Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"

XAML: (this goes directly in the root node)

```
<Window
   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
   xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
   x:Name="window" >
    ...

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlashingBackground, Mode=OneWay}" Value="ON">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}"     
                                                ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
      </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    ...
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
    private void TurnOnFlashingBackround()
    {
        this.FlashingBackground = "ON";
    }

    private string _FlashingBackround = "OFF";

    public string FlashingBackground
    {
        get { return this._FlashingBackround; }

        private set
        {
            if (this.FlashingBackground == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            this._FlashingBackround = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FlashingBackground");
        }
    }

    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, 
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Finally, the Viewmodel must inherit from "INotifyPropertyChanged"

Comment: Also note: you need two assembly references: System.Windows.Interactivity and the above mentioned Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an `EventTrigger`. This [article about Animations in WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/emea/msdn/thepanel/en/articles/animations_wpf.aspx) might help. See also the [Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) on the MSDN and [How to: Use Event Triggers to Control a Storyboard After It Starts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744905.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the pointer, but all the docs for EventTrigger show it being triggered by an event coming off an existing FrameworkElement. I am now firing a RoutedEvent from my ViewModel but can't see how to get the XAML to subscribe:
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="my:NumbersViewModel.RightAnswer">