# What is a model.cs file?

Tags: c#, model, viewmodel

What is a model.cs file?

[image]

This appears in a project I am sharing with other dev's.  What is a model.cs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **ViewModel** Pattern in Silverlight using Behaviors.

Read this thread [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375301/should-i-use-the-model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-pattern-in-silverlight-projects).

Answer (score 0):

In the MVVM pattern, it is common to name the model layer objects in a way that the name reflects the actual usage of the object. The name "model" by itself is often used as an example (to underline the architecture layer to which the object bearing it belongs) but in real world, the model classes contain the business logic of the application and will be named in wildly varied ways.

That said, it could be an auto-generated file/class which is uniquely identified by its namespace instead of the actual name. This is not a bad approach for auto-generated tools but it hinders readability for human coders, should they need to manipulate the objects in question.